# git pull based on SHA

Tags: git

I would like to know how to do a pull from repo based on a SHA?

```
git pull origin master
```

the above code will pull master once we've done `git add remote`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A git pull does two things for you:

1. Fetches a specific branch from the repository
2. Merges it with your current branch.

It sounds like what you want to do is to get a specific revision from the repository and merge it with your current branch.

The best way to do this is two commands:

```
git fetch origin
git merge YOUR_SHA_HERE
```

If what you want is just to see what's in a specific revision from the repository and make it the working tree, but not do a merge, then you would want:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout YOUR_SHA_HERE
```

If what you want is to get the specific version, and make it the new "master" (or another branch), then you would want to run

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard YOUR_SHA_HERE
```

All of these will fetch new code from the repository (via the 'git fetch origin'), but then there are different ways to combine with / replace your current code.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there's a way to pull just part of a branch based on a SHA.

What's wrong with:

```
git pull
git reset --hard <sha>
```